# Rails application deployed on Elastic Beanstalk with Puma fails - 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

when i was deploying new version I ran to this error.  I tried to follow couple instruction on stack-overflow but was no help. when i deploy, The Health status comes as succeed at first then when i visit the website it changes to Degraded. 
On the website I Get the error
 
 
502 Bad Gateway
  
nginx/1.12.1

here is image from nginx/error.log
[image]

error

```
2018/07/22 23:11:55 [error] 3038#0: *5502 connect() to unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 68.228.233.169, server: _, request: "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock:/robots.txt", host: "borroupenv.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com"
2018/07/22 23:11:55 [error] 3038#0: *5498 connect() to unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 68.228.233.169, server: _, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock:/favicon.ico", host: "borroupenv.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com", referrer: "http://borroupenv.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/"
```

this is from puma.rb

```
 threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 }
 threads threads_count, threads_count
 port        ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3000 }
 environment ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV") { "development" }
 bind "unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock"
 pidfile "/var/run/puma/my_app.sock"
 plugin :tmp_restart
```

this is from config/environments/production.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.eager_load = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.read_encrypted_secrets = true
  config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  config.assets.compile = false
  config.log_level = :debug
  config.log_tags = [ :request_id ]
  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
     address: 'smtp.mailgun.org',
     port: 587,
     domain: 'borroup.com',
     enable_starttls_auto: true,
     authentication: 'plain',
     user_name: '',
     password: ''
   } 
   config.i18n.fallbacks = true
   config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
   config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
     if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
     logger           = 
      ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
     logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
     config.logger    = 
     ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
     end
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = 
 false
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the website back on  and solve the Nging error.

It was a result of me being on Mac . When compressing on  Mac it uses the Darwin binary zip file which elastic beanstalk doesn't support. I did it by downloading Keka and zipping it with that tool.